# how to send/echo x (specific) number of messages in a shell script per sec

Tags: shell

How can I send some specific number of, say 1000, messages (echo) per second to a file by a shell script?

i.e. I want to echo 1000 such messages ("hi") per sec to a (tmp) file. 
echo "hi" >> tmp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best you can do is this:

```
while :; do
    i=0
    while [ $i -lt 1000 ]; do
            echo hi >> tmp
            i=$((i+1))
    done
    sleep 1
done
```

The time to actually execute the commands in the inner while loop is not taken into account, so this will write slightly less messages per second.

Comment: Thank you but I have a fundamental question here: What we are doing is, sleeping 1 second between each 1000 messages, how does it ensure that inner while loop is executed in 1 second? Or what I am asking is probably not accurately possible as many things can actually happen with cpu cycles while this is being done. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @hari You are right: You can't be sure and other programs may use CPU cycles. If this solution is good enough depends on the problem you are trying to solve.